# Burning Data+Audio Disc

Tags: cd-burning

It's been a long time since I've ever had to burn something that isn't just a set of data, or an ISO (via Disk Utility), but now I have to burn a Multi-Session disc.

Are there easy ways of burning a data ISO first, followed by MP3s (as standard Redbook Audio tracks), other than paying $80 for Roxio's Toast burning software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this need by using [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html). Drop dead simple burning and quite a few worthwhile features.

(Not to be confused with [Buuurn](http://buuurn.com/)!)

Answer (score 1):

While these instructions on Apple's website ([Apple support doc](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=DiskUtility/10.5/en/duh1749.html)) are for OS X 10.4, they still work in Snow Leopard.  It has been a very long time since I had to do a multi-session CD, but I remember doing this way or in a very similar way. It's worth a try and a CD-R costs a lot less that Toast.

Comment: I don't think that would allow me to burn redbook audio, just the mp3's themselves which wouldn't work. +1 regardless.